# How is the variance schedule used?

Tags: options, variance

Let $v(t)$ be the instantaneous variance of an underlying stock or index at time $t\in[0,1]$ between the open at $t=0$ and close at $t=1$ of an exchange. Usually $v(t)$ achieves local maxima at $t\in\{0,1\}$. For example,
$$v(t)\propto f(t)= a+bt+c\cos(2\pi t), \, c>0,$$
where $\int_0^1 f(t)dt=1$.

I can see $\int_{T_1}^{T_2}v(t)dt$ can be plugged into a model, such as the Black-Scholes formula. But I was told that the functional form is also used to compute some kind of effective variance-time in options pricing/trading?. I am not sure exactly how. Could someone elucidate?

Comment: What matters for pricing an option at time $T_1$ that expires at time $T_2$ is the "integrated variance" $\int_{T_1}^{T_2} \sigma^2(t) dt$. Once you compute this parameter (via your variance schedule or any other) then the option pricing proceeds as normal.

Comment: @nbbo2: I understand that part. I just edited my question. Do you know of the other usage I am asking?

Comment: What is exactly meant here by variance-time and variamce-schedule?

Comment: @FridoRolloos: That is precisely what I want to know. :-D

Comment: Where does the proportionality relationship in your question come from (is this simply an _ad hoc_ assumption?), and what "functional form" are you referring to - the former? I also don't understand what is the relation between $v(t)$ reaching a maximum and your question about "variance-time".

Comment: Aside from that the only bell this question rings is that of [**timer options**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timer_Call), see in particular the paper by Bernard & Cui (2011) in _The Journal of Computational Finance_. Not sure if this has anything to do with your question though...

Comment: As @DaneelOlivaw mentioned, timer options is also the only thing I can think of, although it's usually called business time in that context. I've not come across the term variamce time before but I suspect it may have to do with time changed Brownian motion.

Comment: In the BSM formula the variable $t$ has two purposes: *discount time* appears in the form $e^{-rt}$ while *variance time* appears in the expressions $\sigma^2 t$ or $\sigma \sqrt t$. If desired you can use two variables say $u$ and $v$ instead of one  variable to gain some additional fexibility. This is another way to deal with non-constant variance: let $\sigma^2$ be fixed but play around with the value of $v$.

Comment: @nbbo2: I agree with what you are saying. But what advantage do the change of variables bring us?